# Web application, users and permissions (and security)

Tags: database, security, web-applications, permissions

I'm designing a web application, my first serious web application. It'll have some users with different privileges (RBAC/ACL). As you can imagine, I'm a little bit worried about permission management and security

This is why I was wondering why, in a web application, users are usually stored in the database instead of being database users (e.g. Joomla!). I feel that this is an insecure authentication method: database connection is always done using a db user with full or very high privileges on the db, so what can and can not be done is managed by the web application by writing an RBAC/ACL authorization layer (so I have a bunch of tables in the DB which holds users, privilege levels etc.).

From a conceptual point of view I think that a better approach would be to use more database users (at least one for each level of privileges, or better one for each web application's user) in order to protect the data in the db (if I have a security breach and an attacker finds out the db's connection info, his privileges will be limited by the privileges of the hacked user's account).

I see that this approach is quite clumsy to implement, but on the other hand it's more secure.

Why isn't this approach used? It's just a matter of convenience's sake, or it's a matter of seeking the right tradeoff between security and ease of coding? Or maybe I'm just making a mess and mixing two different things (db and application users) which are meant for two different scopes.

Sorry if the question is stupid, but when studying you learn about DB users and permissions and when you see real software things are done (apparently) in a different way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That approach does sound more secure, but it is an implementation nightmare, and even more so when you start considering scaling to a million+ users :-O

The best approach (from a security standpoint as well as a feasibility standpoint) is to have two user accounts for the DB.  One with read only privileges and one with read/write privileges.  *Only use the read/write credentials when you need to add a user or change a password.*  Don't be stupid with these credentials.  Never let them make it to the client side either in the form of client side code or comments (I've seen DB credentials inside HTML comments *sigh*).

If your app/user base is really small and always will be, then maybe you can have each user account assigned a sandboxed DB account.  That would be more secure.  However I would never assume you'll always have a small user base.  You never know what the future will bring and it would *suck* to have to re-implement that.

Comment: Thank you, I supposed something like this, you confirmed my thoughts ;)